# Get Data from Controller to Column Datatables (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, datatables

I'm trying to get some data from controller action in JSON format through a button view (detail) then send it to the DataTables column, but unfortunately, I didn't succeed to place it into DataTables.

[image]

here are some code my view (v_list.php):

```
var renderACT = function(ROW){
      var viewButton = '<button id="viewrowbutton" type="button" role="button" aria-disabled="false" value="" title="View Data" onclick="VIEW_DETAIL('+ROW+')"  class="jqx-rc-all jqx-rc-all-ui-start jqx-button jqx-button-ui-start jqx-widget jqx-widget-ui-start jqx-fill-state-normal jqx-fill-state-normal-ui-start" style="cursor:pointer;padding: 2px; margin: 2px;float:left;height:30px;width:60px;"><i class="fas fa-info-circle fa-lg fa-fw">&nbsp;</i>Detil</button>';
}

function VIEW_DETAIL(params){
     params=aDATAGRID[params]['ID'];
     params=params.replace(/\//g, '_');
     window.location.href='<?php echo base_url().'index.php/nif/kas/M_index/lihatData/'?>'+params;
     return false;
}
```

And my controller (M_index.php):

```
public function lihatData($filter="get")
{
    $sql_header="select no_dok,pat,dok,subject,ket from tb_fin.dok_h where no_dok='".$filter."'";
    $result_header=$result_header->result();      
    $this->render_view('nif/kas/add_data', $result_header);
}
```

And the output from the controller was:

```
[
        {
            "NO_DOK":"20190A00000001",
            "PAT":"11A",
            "DOK":"P",
            "SUBJECT":"RIZAL",
            "KET":"CONTRACT"
        },
        {
            "NO_DOK":"20190A00000001",
            "PAT":"12A",
            "DOK":"P",
            "SUBJECT":"RIZAL",
            "KET":"CONTRACT"
        }
]
```

I want to put my output just like above in my form add (add_data.php):

```
   <table id="tblmemorialdetil" class="stripe row-border">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>No Dok</th>
                            <th>PAT</th>
                            <th>DOKUMEN</th>
                            <th>SUBJEK</th>
                            <th>KETERANGAN</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <?php
                            $strDetail="";

                            for($i=0;$i<20;$i++){
                                $strDetail.="<tr>";
                                $strDetail.="<td style=\"text-align:right;\">".($i+1).".</td>";
                                $strDetail.="<td><select id='txtDok".$i."' name='txtDok[]".$i."' class=\"akun\" style=\"width:500px;\"></select></td>";
                                $strDetail.="<td><select name='txtPat[]".$i."' class=\"pat\" style=\"width:200px;\"></select></td>";
                                $strDetail.="<td><select name='txtDokumen[]".$i."' class=\"dokumen\" style=\"width:200px;\"></select></td>";
                                $strDetail.="<td><select type='text' class=\"subject\" name='txtSubject[]".$i."' value=\"\" style=\"text-align:left;width:140px;\"/></td>";
                                $strDetail.="<td><select type='text' class=\"keterangan\" name='txtKet[]".$i."' value=\"\" style=\"text-align:left;width:140px;\"/></td>";
                            }
                            echo $strDetail;
                        ?>
                        </tbody>
   </table>

   $(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#tblmemorialdetil').DataTable( {
        scrollY:        "400px",
        scrollX:        true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        paging:         false,
        bInfo        : false,
        fixedColumns:   {
            leftColumns: 2,
            rightColumns: 1
        }
     });
    });
```

How could I put it my array output into my table? Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First your `controller (M_index.php)` should be like this,

```
public function lihatData($filter="get")
{
    $sql_header = "select no_dok,pat,dok,subject,ket from tb_fin.dok_h where no_dok='".$filter."'";
    $result_header['results'] = $result_header->result();      
    $this->render_view('nif/kas/add_data', $result_header);
}
```

And then in your `view`, you can iterate your results that receiving from your controller like this.

```
<?php 

$i=0;
foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo $result[$i]->NO_DOK;
    $i++;
}

?>
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: how could "i" come from?

Comment: @baimWonk I have updated the answer. I missed some statements.

Comment: And how to echo in my view then? I mean to fill in the right field

Comment: Where you need to echo them? I can't see a place.

Comment: I need to echo each of it on <td select......  @Hasitha Jayawardana

Comment: Show me the exact code snippet that you need to fetch data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202538/discussion-between-baimwonk-and-hasitha-jayawardana).